# TestNGException: parameter 'userid' is required

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
  <Parameter name="userid" value="pallatirkak"/>
   <Parameter name="criteria" value="invalid"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="moduledriven.Testclassformoduledriver"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testclassformoduledriver 
{
    public WebDriver darling;
    @Test(priority=0)
    public void launch() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ishu\\chromedriver.exe");
        darling=new ChromeDriver();
        darling.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    @Parameters({"userid","criteria"})
     public void useridtest(String u,String c) throws Exception
     {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        darling.findElement(By.name("identifier")).sendKeys(u,Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        if(c.equalsIgnoreCase("valid")&&darling.findElement(By.name("password")).isDisplayed())
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);


        }
        else if(c.equals("invalid")&&darling.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Couldn') or contains(text(),'Enter an email')]")).isDisplayed())
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }


     }
    @Test(priority=2)
     public void close() throws Exception
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            darling.close();
        }
```

Error:

> `useridtest org.testng.TestNGException`: Parameter 'userid' is required
>   by @Test on method useridtest but has not been marked Optional or
>   defined in C:\Users\ishu2\pomproject\src\lovely.xml ... Removed 23
>   stack frames

Comment: useridtest
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'userid' is required by @Test on method useridtest but has not been marked Optional or defined
in C:\Users\ishu2\pomproject\src\lovely.xml
... Removed 23 stack frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing TestNG's xml is case sensitive? Have you tried

`<parameter name="userid" value="pallatirkak"/>
<parameter name="criteria" value="invalid"/>`